# Viewcontroller basics - What am I missing?

Tags: iphone, ios, viewcontroller

I'm a newbie App developer.

I've been following a few books including the sams "teach yourself iPhone development". (which is based on a slightly outdated version of Xcode).

Even with these discrepancies, I'd assume that when you start a "view based" project and dump some buttons and labels onto the myappViewController.xib it would push it to the window of the mainwindow.xib without having to do any kind of linking? right?

What am I missing?

So I'm following the steps :

**1) Start view based app**

**2) Add a button to the myappviewcontroller.xib**

**3) Compile app.**

Why am I getting a white page that says "text". I haven't added a label, and I can't find "text" as a variable in anything..

Comment: Hi, hard to say to be honest, my advice would be just to delete it and start again from scratch working through things slowly, [here](http://paulpeelen.com/2011/03/17/xcode-4-ios-4-3-hello-world/) is quite a nice tutorial for x-code 4, sorry couldn't be of more help

Answer (score 0):

Might be that you just need to set the window's Root View Controller in the `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of your App Delegate?

Answer (score 0):

Find the xib in your project that gets generated with the project, probably MainView or something like that unless things have changed since Storyboards were introduced.  Click on that xib in the list of files to show Interface Builder in the pane on the right.  There should be whatever graphical elements that you aren't finding in code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are getting "text" showing up however I would suggest using the latest Xcode for your projects for no other reason than the Storyboard feature takes a lot of the newbie headaches out of getting used to .xib linking.

If you want to test a button though you can use this code to get started:

In ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIButton *buttonName;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *buttonName;

@end
```

And then in ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize buttonName;

@end
```